# Why method take struct pointer as input can modify its field value meanwhile a method take struct as input can't?

Tags: go

I'm study learning golang recently. And today I encounter a phenomenon which confused me.

Below is my code snippet:

```
package main // what does package main mean?

import (
    "strings"
)

type Queue struct {
    Name string
}

func NewQueue(name string) Queue {
    return Queue{name}
}

func (q Queue) MagicMethod(word string) {
    str_list := []string {q.Name, word}
    new_str := strings.Join(str_list[:], "")
    println("MagicMethod-new_str:", new_str)
    q.Name = new_str
    println("MagicMethod-Queue.Name:", q.Name)
}

func main() {
    x := NewQueue("xxx")
    x.MagicMethod("y")
    println("main-Queue.Name:", x.Name)
    x.MagicMethod("z")
    println("main-Queue.Name:", x.Name)
}
```

My intention is to build a method for Queue, which can append new string to its Name. But this code didn't realize my intention. Its output is:

```
MagicMethod-new_str: xxxy
MagicMethod-Queue.Name: xxxy
main-Queue.Name: xxx
MagicMethod-new_str: xxxz
MagicMethod-Queue.Name: xxxz
main-Queue.Name: xxx
```

Which confused me, from the output I can see that inside the MagicMethod, the value for q.Name has changed corresponds to the input arg. But it didn't affect the Name of outside Queue - x.

I did some experiment then and found if I change `func (q Queue) MagicMethod(word string)` to `func (q *Queue) MagicMethod(word string)`， I can get the result I preferred, which is:

```
MagicMethod-new_str: xxxy
MagicMethod-Queue.Name: xxxy
main-Queue.Name: xxxy
MagicMethod-new_str: xxxyz
MagicMethod-Queue.Name: xxxyz
main-Queue.Name: xxxyz
```

But still I don't know the mechanism why this works.
So, why did the first method which takes `q Queue` as input does changed the Name field inside the MagicMethod but didn't change it outside of the method? What's the mechanism of it?

Comment: Please take the tour of go, specifically https://tour.golang.org/methods/8

Comment: @Marc, I did that 2 or 3 times several months ago, but it still didn't explains why this happened.

Comment: The `q` "inside" is a copy if the `q` "outside". Changing a copy never changes the original.

Comment: @Volker, thanks, before you explain it, I don't know that golang will pass a copy of it to the method.

Comment: This "issue" is not Go-specific, so you might try studying anything you can find about what a pointer is. C is supposedly the closest to Go in these semantics.

Comment: Everything is passed by value (copy) in Go and that is clearly explained in the Tour of Go, especially the slides liked by Marc.

Answer (score 2):

Its because methods with pointer receivers, i.e. ones taking type `q *Queue`,  can modify the value to which the receiver points.

- In  value receivers (ones taking type `q Queue`), a *copy* of the arguments are passed to the method, because of which any changes to the copy, does not reflect back in the caller.
- In case of pointer receivers, the method gets the "actual" parameters passed

Quoting the example from - https://tour.golang.org/methods/4, its because the `Scale` function is called as a pointer receiver as

```
func (v *Vertex) Scale(f float64) {
```

the vertex co-ordinates `X, Y` are multiplied by the scale factor `10`. Note that the `Abs()` function just takes a value receiver as it just performs the `Sqrt` function on the vertex co-ordinates.

Try modifying the `Scale` function to operate as a value receiver (removing `*` in `(v *Vertex)` and see the result and compare it with one received from retaining it.

Answer (score 2):

`func (q Queue) MagicMethod(word string) {` is a "value receiver". It makes a copy of the Queue. Any changes you make to `q` are to the copy inside the method. TO see the changes you'd have to return `q`.

`func (q *Queue) MagicMethod(word string) {` is a "pointer receiver". It does not make a copy. Any changes you make to `q` are on the original struct.

See [Effective Go - Pointers vs Values](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#pointers_vs_values).

> The rule about pointers vs. values for receivers is that value methods can be invoked on pointers and values, but pointer methods can only be invoked on pointers.

> ...pointer methods can modify the receiver; invoking them on a value would cause the method to receive a copy of the value, so any modifications would be discarded.